# Cambiar propiedades html según perfil de acceso y bloquear los inputs para que no puedan modificar datos

Tags: php, html

Cómo hago para cambiar las propiedades html según perfil de acceso y bloquear los inputs para que no puedan modificar datos, quiero usar un readonly pero con condiciones.

```html
<form class="form" action="{$fsc->url()}" method="post" id="Datos" name="Datos" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            {if="!$fsc->user->admin"}
            <h1>Usted no puede hacer modificaciones en este apartado</h1>
            {/if}
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="background-color: #ddd">
                        <label for="title">
                            <h3><b>Datos del estudiante</b></h3>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="idestudiante" id="idestudiante" class="form-control" value="{$fsc->estudiante->idestudiante}">


                    
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="date">Nombre 1:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="est_primernombre" id="est_primernombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre 1" value="{$fsc->estudiante->est_primernombre}">
                        
                    </div>


                  
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="date">Nombre 2:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="est_segundonombre" id="est_segundonombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre 2" value="{$fsc->estudiante->est_segundonombre}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label for="date">Apellido 1:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="est_primerapellido" id="est_primerapellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido 1" value="{$fsc->estudiante->est_primerapellido}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label for="date">Apellido 2:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="est_segundoapellido" id="est_segundoapellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido 2" value="{$fsc->estudiante->est_segundoapellido}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label for="date">Correo:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="est_correo" id="est_correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" value="{$fsc->estudiante->est_correo}">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <br>
                        <label for="Status">Carrera:</label>
                        <select name="idcarrera" id="idcarrera" class="form-control">
                            {loop="$fsc->carrera"}
                            <option value="{$value['idcarrera']}">{$value['carrera']}</option>
                            {/loop}
                            {loop="$fsc->carreras"}
                            <option value="{$value['idcarrera']}">{$value['carrera']}</option>
                            {/loop}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {if="$fsc->estudiante->en_proceso_t == 0"}
            <label for="title">
                {if="$fsc->user->admin"}
                <input type="checkbox" id="en_proceso_t" name="en_proceso_t" value="1">
                <b>Señalar Estudiante en proceso de titulación</b>
                {/if}
            </label>
            {else}
            <input type="checkbox" id="en_proceso_t" name="en_proceso_t" value="1" checked hidden>
          
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="background-color: #ddd">
                        <label for="title">
                            <h3><b>Proceso de titulación</b></h3>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <label for="title">
                        <h4><b>Tema del proyecto</b></h4>
                    </label>
                    <div class="form-group">                            
                        <input type="text" name="tema" id="tema" class="form-control" value="{$fsc->estudiante->tema}">
                    </div>
                    {if="$fsc->grupos($fsc->estudiante->idestudiante, $fsc->estudiante->tema) > 0"}
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Alumnos involucrados en el proyecto</th>
                        </tr>
                        {loop="$fsc->grupos($fsc->estudiante->idestudiante, $fsc->estudiante->tema)"}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{$value['alumno']}</td>

                            <input type="hidden" id="idgrupo" name="idgrupo[]" value="{$value['idgrupo']}">
                        </tr>
                        {/loop}
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nota: Las modificaciones que haga sobre este proceso afectará de la misma manera a los alumnos involucrados en el proyecto.</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                    {/if}
```

Comment: Puedes añadir las opciones de ['readonly'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefreadonly) a los elementos que no quieres que edite el usuario sin permisos. Pero de todos formas, en el lado del servidor, al procesar los formularios debes comprobar que el usuario tiene o no los permisos adecuados.

Comment: si añado readonly afecta a todo, los usuarios ya estan con sus roles,

Comment: ¿Dónde colocas tu el 'readonly'? Yo me refería a que los colocases **solo** en los inputs que no quieres que editen los usuarios sin los permisos necesarios.